# Configuring Lift for jQueryUI

Tags: jquery-ui, lift

Lift Framework seems to need a lot of very specific configuration to serve static files.  This is pretty tough if you want to use something like jQueryUI with Lift.  Can anyone point me to a Lift project that has all the configuration necessary to use jQueryUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No extra configuration is needed to use JQuery UI with Lift. Simply put the JS files into the webapp directory like you would with any other static resource. The servlet container will serve that exactly like it would for any other WAR application.

You only need to resource server stuff if you want to serve files from deep in your class path (like from another JAR for example)

Comment: One quick follow up, what is the correct directory for the static files?  The documentation doesn't really seem to spell that out?

Comment: @joe, src/main/webapp/. Maven set the standard that also SBT use: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html